# how to get started with a project

Tags: tcl

I have to write a program that tests products fully automatic.

I still don't have the finished prototype board but i have an development board for the I.MX6UL processor 
see picture below 
http://www.nxp.com/products/sensors/gyroscopes/i.mx6ultralite-evaluation-kit:MCIMX6UL-EVK?

My first task is to put an uboot and linux file system on the board trought TCL code => asked by customer.

This all have to be done trough a usb connection that is connected to the development kit board.

NXP provide some tools that is called MFGTOOL2 => with this i can install a fully working linux but ofcourse i need to do this with code scripting and not via a tool because it's for production testing.

All this has to be installed on an nand flash ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and likely to not be useful to others as so much of it looks specific to your development environment. This means that the first step is going to be for you to do some research so that you can learn how to split the project up into smaller tasks that are more easily achievable. One of the key things is likely to be identifying a mechanism — *any* mechanism — for achieving what you want in terms of communication (and enumerating exactly what are the things that will be communicating!) Once you know what program to run, API to call or message to send, you can then think “How do I do that in Tcl?” but until you are clear what you are trying to do, you won't get good answers from anyone else. Indeed, right now your question is so vague that we could answer “write some programs” and have that be a precisely correct (but unhelpful) reply to you.

You might want to start by identifying in your head whether the program will be running on the board, or on the system that is connected to the board, or on a system that is remote from both of those and that will be doing more complex management from afar.

Comment: Hey Donal,

Thanks for the Reply. I will put that in mind. Sorry for the vaque question.